# Return Pointer to Array in Gmock

Tags: googletest, googlemock

I have a function `uint32_t* GetArrayPointer() {}` which returns a Pointer to an array of `uint32`. Later in my code I go through that array and do some calculation with the values. Now i want to mock the function in my test. So i do

```
MOCK_METHOD0(GetArrayPointer,uint32_t*())
```

And in my test

```
Uint32_t testArray[6] = {...}
EXPECT_CALL(mockObject,GetArrayPointer()).WillRepeatedly(Return(testArray));

FunctionCall()...
```

But with this code I get a segfault.

How can I return the Pointer to my `testArray`?

Answer (score 0):

The code looked fine for returning the array as a pointer, since the array will decay into a pointer when passing it as an argument to the function.

I am guessing that the function `uint32_t* GetArrayPointer()` is a global function, which the function mocking is not allowed, we need to create a wrapper function to wrap it.

Related link:
[How can I effectively test against the Windows API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2611280/how-can-i-effectively-test-against-the-windows-api)

Answer (score 0):

try to use `ReturnPointee` instead, as `Return` only returns a copy of the pointer and not the actual pointer