# How to get list of files in a directory programmatically

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I have searched everything , but no source codes i found work with VS C++ 2008,
Do you have any way to find list of files in a directory programmatically?

I am using VS 2008  C++ on Windows.

Comment: please show what you have tried and explain what doesn't work

Comment: Have you really tried? This is the first result google will give you http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/9173/

Comment: You might want to look at both the question and answers at: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2531874/179910 (he edited code into the question, so it has a possible answer as well...)

Comment: all of this code nee dirent.h and it is not in windows !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This shall find the list of files in `C:` drive, It doesn't use `dirent.h` just simple file handling api's,
***[FindFirstFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*** & ***[FindNextFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364428%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)***

```
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   WIN32_FIND_DATA search_data;

   memset(&search_data, 0, sizeof(WIN32_FIND_DATA));

   HANDLE handle = FindFirstFile("c:\\*", &search_data);

   while(handle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
   {
      cout<<"\n"<<search_data.cFileName;

      if(FindNextFile(handle, &search_data) == FALSE)
        break;
   }

   //Close the handle after use or memory/resource leak
   FindClose(handle);
   return 0;
}
```

You should have a look at the standard api's on the msdn website.

Comment: windows api examples are always ugly

Comment: @Gene Bushuyev: OP asked for one.

Comment: @AlokSave you cannot write search_data.cFileName to standard out. cFileName is a WCHAR.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using Boost, then you can use boost::filesystem.

If you are using Qt, then you can use QDir.

Comment: +1 for boost.filesystem. That one is almost part of the C++ standard and everyone wants it in there, so look for it in the next TR... in the meantime, that fine boost library will save you a ton of headache and writing. Give it a try.