# Importing a list of files in a subdirectory into an array

Tags: c++, filesystems

I am working on a program which requires me to, at multiple points, import the contents of a subdirectory of my C++ Project, into a `vector<string>`. Assuming the project directory is called `root\` and the directory I want to scan is `root\userFiles`. This folder only contains additional files and no further subfolders.

However the trick is I am restricted, I cannot use any of the boost, dirent.h header files. Just the basic ones.

One solution I was able to come up with was the use of the command `system( "dir /b * > userFiles/fileList.txt" );` and then filter the results in by reading that file and importing it into the vector.

My issue is how do I "cd" to that folder, run that command while still in that folder, and then exit back to the root folder..

I have tried using the `system("chdir userFiles/")`command but I am still getting all the files in the root folder.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you use `chdir` (or `_chdir` it may be under Windows) to move to another directory FIRST, then run `system`, it would work as you expect. Otherwise there are plenty of questions with good answers describing how you actually get the names of files of a directory on here.

Comment: As I have specified in the question. `chdir` does not seem to work. I get a list of all the files in the whole of root folder. As for the answers, most of them require me using some sort of third party header file which I cannot use.

Comment: I'm assuming you are using "windows", in which case you should be able to use `<windows.h>` right? If you can't use `windows.h`, then I would use fstream to build a batch file that contains the `"cd directory-you-want\ndir /b"`.

Comment: Like this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6320573/how-to-get-list-of-files-in-a-directory-programatically

Comment: I cannot use `windows.h` haha. Fortunately I have worked out a way to run all those commands in the same system command. `chdir userFiles && dir /b * > fileList.txt && chdir ../`. Works like a charm. Thanks a lot for the help :)

Comment: Who sets these bizarre requirements - and more importantly, to what purpose? Pure sadism or misguided belief that the student will actually learn something more than that the teacher is a sadist?

Comment: Haha, tell me about it. This whole project I can have it done in a week if only the req were removed haha :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I worked out an easier way of doing this.

```
int main()
{
system("chdir userFiles && dir /b * > fileList.txt");
}
```

I am using the `&&` operator to join together multiple strings of commands. Since I am only using the `system()` function once all these commands will be part of the same process.

Comment: No point in doing `chdir ...` - the "new" directory is only active whilst the shell process is still active, so when you the command completes, the parent process will still have its current working directory where it used to be.